# How to convert a csv file to parquet

Tags: java, parquet

I'm new to BigData. I need to convert a `.csv`/`.txt` file to Parquet format. I searched a lot but couldn't find any direct way to do so. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 52):

I already posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691441/2063031) on how to do this using Apache Drill. However, if you are familiar with Python, you can now do this using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/)!

#### Install dependencies

Using `pip`:

```
pip install pandas pyarrow
```

or using `conda`:

```
conda install pandas pyarrow -c conda-forge
```

#### Convert CSV to Parquet in chunks

```
# csv_to_parquet.py

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

csv_file = '/path/to/my.tsv'
parquet_file = '/path/to/my.parquet'
chunksize = 100_000

csv_stream = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='\t', chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False)

for i, chunk in enumerate(csv_stream):
    print("Chunk", i)
    if i == 0:
        # Guess the schema of the CSV file from the first chunk
        parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk).schema
        # Open a Parquet file for writing
        parquet_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(parquet_file, parquet_schema, compression='snappy')
    # Write CSV chunk to the parquet file
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)
    parquet_writer.write_table(table)

parquet_writer.close()
```

I haven't benchmarked this code against the Apache Drill version, but in my experience it's plenty fast, converting tens of thousands of rows per second (this depends on the CSV file of course!).

---

**Edit:**

We can now read CSV files directly into PyArrow Tables using  [`pyarrow.csv.read_csv`](http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.read_csv.html). This is probably faster than using the Pandas CSV reader, although it may be less flexible.

Comment: Why is it less flexible? (Sorry, I don't have experience working with `pyarrow`, just got curious seeing your comment)

Comment: @sphoenix I was mostly refering to the number of parameters accepted by the [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and  [`pyarrow.csv.read_csv`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.read_csv.html) methods.

To give a specific example, the case of `pd.read_csv`, `sep="..."` can be a regular expression, while in the case of `pyarrow.csv.read_csv`, `delimiter="..."` has to be a single character.

Comment: There is risk of schema error in this code as the schema of the entire CSV is being inferred from the first chunk of data. The first chunk may falsely indicate a column as int, but the last chunk may contain decimal or empty values, resulting in error when writing the parquet file.  The solution would be to infer data types based on phased reading of the entire CSV before creating the parquet file schema. The proposed code is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74871381)

Answer (score 36):

[**For Python**]

Pandas now has direct support for it.

Just read the csv file into dataframe by pandas using [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and writing that dataframe to parquet file using [to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html).

Comment: why would you offer python solution for a Java question?

Comment: Because there was already one without mentioning to_parquet (as it was released with 0.21.0). Thought this might be useful for someone who requires a python based solution.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/), as described in [Convert a CSV File to Apache Parquet With Drill](http://tgrall.github.io/blog/2015/08/17/convert-csv-file-to-apache-parquet-dot-dot-dot-with-drill/).

In brief:

Start Apache Drill:

```
$ cd /opt/drill/bin
$ sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local
```

Create the Parquet file:

```
-- Set default table format to parquet
ALTER SESSION SET `store.format`='parquet';

-- Create a parquet table containing all data from the CSV table
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.`/stats/airport_data/` AS
SELECT
CAST(SUBSTR(columns[0],1,4) AS INT)  `YEAR`,
CAST(SUBSTR(columns[0],5,2) AS INT) `MONTH`,
columns[1] as `AIRLINE`,
columns[2] as `IATA_CODE`,
columns[3] as `AIRLINE_2`,
columns[4] as `IATA_CODE_2`,
columns[5] as `GEO_SUMMARY`,
columns[6] as `GEO_REGION`,
columns[7] as `ACTIVITY_CODE`,
columns[8] as `PRICE_CODE`,
columns[9] as `TERMINAL`,
columns[10] as `BOARDING_AREA`,
CAST(columns[11] AS DOUBLE) as `PASSENGER_COUNT`
FROM dfs.`/opendata/Passenger/SFO_Passenger_Data/*.csv`;
```

Try selecting data from the new Parquet file:

```
-- Select data from parquet table
SELECT *
FROM dfs.tmp.`/stats/airport_data/*`
```

You can change the `dfs.tmp` location by going to `http://localhost:8047/storage/dfs` (source: [CSV and Parquet](http://www.vitarkah.com/2016/03/10/csv-files-and-apache-parquet/)).

Comment: I confirm this is the best and easiest way to achieve this. Apache Hive could be an alternative too.

Answer (score 7):

The following code is an example using spark2.0. Reading is much faster than inferSchema option. Spark 2.0 convert into parquet file in much more efficient than spark1.6.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
var df = StructType(Array(StructField("timestamp", StringType, true),StructField("site", StringType, true),StructField("requests", LongType, true) ))
df = spark.read
          .schema(df)
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("delimiter", "\t")
          .csv("/user/hduser/wikipedia/pageviews-by-second-tsv")
df.write.parquet("/user/hduser/wikipedia/pageviews-by-second-parquet")
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a small command line tool to convert CSV to Parquet: [`csv2parquet`](https://github.com/domoritz/arrow-tools/tree/main/crates/csv2parquet)

Answer (score 3):

1) You can create an external hive table

```
create  external table emp(name string,job_title string,department string,salary_per_year int)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
location '.. hdfs location of csv file '
```

2) Another hive table that will store parquet file

```
create  external table emp_par(name string,job_title string,department string,salary_per_year int)
row format delimited
stored as PARQUET
location 'hdfs location were you want the save parquet file'
```

Insert the table one data into table two :

```
insert overwrite table emp_par select * from emp
```

Comment: Table emp_par has been created as EXTERNAL TABLE. This should have been created as normal table or else you can't insert data into it.

Answer (score 2):

Read csv files as [Dataframe in Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) with [spark-csv package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). after loading data to Dataframe save dataframe to parquetfile.

```
val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .load("/home/myuser/data/log/*.csv")
df.saveAsParquetFile("/home/myuser/data.parquet")
```

Comment: The `spark-csv` package is deprecated because the functionalities have been included in Spark 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the csv2parquet tool from https://github.com/fraugster/parquet-go project. It is much simpler to use than Apache Drill

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
sqlContext = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.csv('file:///xxx/xxx.csv')
df.write.parquet('file:///xxx/output.parquet')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import sys

sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col4", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col5", StringType(), True)])
rdd = sc.textFile('/input.csv').map(lambda line: line.split(","))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.write.parquet('/output.parquet')
```