# How to Convert Pandas Data Frame Schema

Tags: python, pandas, schema, parquet, pyarrow

I am reading a CSV file with `pandas.read_csv` and it detects the schema automatically which is like

```
Column1: string
Column2: string
Column3: string
Column4: int64
Column5: double
Column6: double
__index_level_0__: int64
```

Then, I am trying to write it with `pyarrow.parquet.write_table`  as a Parquet table. However, I want to use the following schema for the new parquet file

```
Column1: string
Column2: string
Column3: string
Column4: string
Column5: string
Column6: string
__index_level_0__: int64
```

But I get an error saying "Table schema does not match schema used to create file". Here is the piece of code I have used to convert a CSV file to a Parquet file [borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124417/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-parquet)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

csv_file = 'C:/input.csv'
parquet_file = 'C:/putput.parquet'
chunksize = 100_000

csv_stream = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',', chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")

for i, chunk in enumerate(csv_stream):
    print("Chunk", i)
    if i == 0:
        # Guess the schema of the CSV file from the first chunk
        # parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk).schema
        parquet_schema = pa.schema([
            ('c1', pa.string()),
            ('c2', pa.string()),
            ('c3', pa.string()),
            ('c4', pa.string()),
            ('c5', pa.string()),
            ('c6', pa.string())
        ])
        # Open a Parquet file for writing
        parquet_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(parquet_file, parquet_schema, compression='snappy')
    # Write CSV chunk to the parquet file
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)
    parquet_writer.write_table(table)

parquet_writer.close()
```

Comment: What is the schema of `table` right before it is written (where you get the error)?

Comment: It is the same as the automatically detected schema

Comment: OK, `table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)` should give you a table with the coerced schema. If not, it's a bug and please open a JIRA issue if possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`df=df.astype(str)` will convert all of the data in a pandas dataframe in strings, with `object` dtypes using the built-in [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method

You can also change the type of a single column, for example `df['Column4'] = df['Column4'].astype(str)`.

All you need to do is to change the type of your dataframe or a subset of its columns before `parquet_writer.write_table(table)`. Altogether, your code would look like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

csv_file = 'C:/input.csv'
parquet_file = 'C:/putput.parquet'
chunksize = 100_000

def convert(df):
    df['Column4'] = df['Column4'].astype(str)
    return df

csv_stream = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',', chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")

for i, chunk in enumerate(csv_stream):
    print("Chunk", i)
    if i == 0:            
        converted = convert(chunk)
        parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=converted).schema

        # Open a Parquet file for writing
        parquet_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(parquet_file, parquet_schema, compression='snappy')

    # Write CSV chunk to the parquet file
    converted = convert(chunk)
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(converted, parquet_schema)
    parquet_writer.write_table(table)

parquet_writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, how is it possible to convert only the type of a column in a dataframe?

Comment: Exactly the same way, luckily `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)`

Comment: It's good that there's a workaround but I'm concerned there's a bug in pyarrow that needs to be reported