# Converting CSV to Parquet File format using Script in SAP BODS

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pyarrow, sap-data-services

BODS job is creating CSV Files.

Is there a way to convert CSV Files to Parquet and Upload to S3 Bucket in SAP BODS.

The Current approach I am using is below for Converting the CSV to Parquet.

1. Create a CSV File in the Folder that BODS is accessable.
2. Created a Python Script  and placed the Script in the Package Folder and below is the code:

```
import os,sys
os.chdir("/usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append('/usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/ds_ext_share/BODS_DEV/Output/xxxx.csv')
df.to_parquet('/ds_ext_share/BODS_DEV/Output/xxxx.parquet')
```

3. I am calling the above script as Exec in my BODS Job in a script:

```
exec('/usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages','XXXX.py' , '8');
```

The above code is not working because the CSV file is not converting to Parquet. How can I make it convert?

Comment: Didn't get how pyarrow was involved in this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your python code works as expected, it can read CSV file and write to parquet file.

The problem is the `exec()` function call in your BODS script.

```
exec('/usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages','XXXX.py' , '8');
```

`exec()` is to call shell command or script, first parameter is shell command or shell script, second parameter will be passed to shell command or shell script; the last parameter is how `exec()` ran, either return error, if wait for shell command or shell complete.

Please refer to [SAP HELP](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_DATA_SERVICES/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/5761b3486d6d1014b3fc9283b0e91070.html).

The BODS script should be like below:

```
exec('/path/to/python/python', '/usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/XXXX.py', 8);
```

Or create shell script `bods.sh`:

```
python /usr/sap/DBO/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/XXXX.py
```

Then BODS script:

```
exec('bods.sh',8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing BODS from the equation the question remains how to convert a CSV file to parquet in python [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/)!
This has been asked and answered in a similar thread here.

- [How to convert a csv file to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618618)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).