# How can I fix the 'line x did not have y elements' error when trying to use read.csv.sql?

Tags: r, csv, sqldf, read.csv

I am a relative beginner to R trying to load and explore a large (7GB) CSV file.

It's from the Open Food Facts database and the file is downloadable here: https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data (the raw csv link).

It's too large to read straight into R and my searching has made me think the `sqldf` package could be useful. But when I try and read the file in with this code ...

```
library(sqldf)
library(here)

read.csv.sql(here("02. Data", "en.openfoodfacts.org.products.csv"), sep = "\t")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 10 did not have 196 elements
```

Searching around made me think it's because there are missing values in the data. With `read.csv`, it looks like you can set `fill = TRUE` and get around this. But I can't work out how to do this with the `read.csv.sql` function. I also can't actually open the csv in Excel to inspect it because it's too large.

Does anyone know how to solve this or if there is a better method for reading in this large file? Please keep in mind I don't really know how to use SQL or other database tools, mostly just R (but can try and learn the basics if helpful).

Comment: Try data.table's `fread` function.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but got the following error:

`Error in fread(here("02. Data", "en.openfoodfacts.org.products.csv"),  : 
  Opened 6.970GB (7484470456 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 64bit process. There is probably not enough contiguous virtual memory available.`

Comment: With a 7GB CSV file, there is nothing you can do to read it into your R instance. I suggest some alternatives for working with data that large, assuming that you're really only looking at a (significantly smaller) subset of it at any one time: [`arrow`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow), [`disk.frame`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame), or load into a database (e.g., monolithic like [`duckdb`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/duckdb) or [`RSQLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite), or a DBMS such as PostgreSQL, MariaDB, or SQL Server).

Comment: However, since parquet (arrow) files cannot be easily concatenated (without loading into memory), your better bet might be to use one of the DBMS options. (Though once in duckdb, one can [export to parquet](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/parquet_export.html) directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, it seems unlikely that you can read the CSV file en toto into memory, even once. I suggest for analyzing the data within it, you may need to change your data-access to something else, such as:

- DBMS, whether monolithic ([`duckdb`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/duckdb) or [`RSQLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite), lower cost-of-entry) or full DBMS (e.g., PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQL Server). With this method, you would connect (using `DBI`) to the database (monolithic or otherwise), query for the subset of data you want/need, and work on *that* data. It is feasible to do in-database aggregation as well, which might be a necessary step in your analysis.
- Arrow parquet file. These are directly supported by `dplyr` functions and *in a lazy fashion*, meaning that when you call `open_dataset("path/to/my.parquet")`, it immediately returns an object but does not load data; you call your dplyr `mutate`/`filter`/`select`/`summarize` pipe (some limitations), and then you finally call `... %>% collect()`, *only then* it loads the resulting data into memory. Similar to SQL above in that you work on subsets at a time, but if you're already familiar with `dplyr`, it is much much closer than learning SQL from scratch.

There are ways to get a large CSV file into each of this.

- Arrow/Parquet: [How to convert a csv file to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124417/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-parquet) ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618618/3358272),
  [arrow/drill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691441/3358272)), a quick search in your favorite search-engine should provide other possibilities; regardless of the language you want to do your analysis in ("R"), don't constrain yourself to solutions using that language.
- SQL: DuckDB (https://duckdb.org/docs/data/csv.html), SQLite (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/), and other DBMSes tend to have a "bulk" command for importing raw CSV.